# Lambda function in pd df with if statement result in Syntax Error

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a df, where in one column contains values in the form of strings which includes numbers & nan values.
That column is represented in the form of string, where each values in the string seperated `using :(colan)instead of , (comma)`(see below column no n represeneted as cln)

```html
index cl1   cl2    .... cln
0      1.1  6.4    .    '12.30 : 14.27 : nan : 15.87, nan .....'
1      2    5.3         '12.8 : 13.73 : nan : 15.87, 12.8 .....'
2      5    6.6
.     .     . 
.     .     .
.     .     .
.    
m     cl1m cl2m          '12.8 : 13.73 : nan : 15.87, 12.8 .....'
```

I want to replace : instead of comma using a single line of code using lambda fn.

```
df['cln'] = df['cln'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(':', ',') if x != np.nan)
```

But i received the following error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even i tried the below code but it shows the same error

```
df['cln'] = df['cln'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(':', ',') if type(x) = str)
# since nan is float
```

**i know how to use for loop and solve this problem, but i just want to know why it doesn't work using Lambda fn**

Expecting pythonic answers for this problem

Comment: You need to have `else` clause to `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `else`:

```py
df['cln'] = df['cln'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(':', ',') if x != np.nan else x)
```

Or better yet, just filter out the null:

```py
df[df['cln'].notnull()].apply(lambda x: x.replace(':', ','))
```

Otherwise, you could see this result:

```py
np.nan == np.nan
False
np.nan != np.nan
True
```